# Table X already exists using Create view X as - MySql

Tags: mysql, view, create-table

I'm doing :

```
create view WritersCouples as
select researcher.serial_number as S1, researcher.firstname as S2
from researcher, researcher as rs
where researcher.serial_number <> rs.serial_number;
```

And i'm getting the following error :

```
Error Code: 1050. Table 'WritersCouples' already exists
```

I'm using workbench over mySql

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following:

```
create or replace view myview
as
select ....
```

Comment: @SagiLow here is the [create view syntax from MYSQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Did you already create the view? or do you already have a table named `WritersCouples`?

You could try this:

```
create or replace view WritersCouples as
select researcher.serial_number as S1, researcher.firstname as S2
from researcher, researcher as rs
where researcher.serial_number <> rs.serial_number;
```

Which would replace the view if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

If the view already exists, add the `OR REPLACE` clause:

```
create OR REPLACE view WritersCouples as
select researcher.serial_number as S1, researcher.firstname as S2
from researcher, researcher as rs
where researcher.serial_number <> rs.serial_number;
```